# Include separate HTML which includes code in the <head>

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I have a bunch of `link` tags in the  tag of my HTML document. Is there any way I can put all of this in a separate HTML document and just link to that one?

E.g turn this:

```
</head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

Into this:

```
<head>
    <link href="head.html" type="text/html">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

With the separate file `head.html` containing all those links?

Comment: Do you mind to use JQuery??

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: @euvl yup but in that solution they are using JQuery

Comment: *Server Side Include* (SSI)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Answer (score 0):

You can include all your stylesheets in one stylesheet with the include method like follows:

CSS:

```
include 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:700'
include 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300'
include 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300'
```

and then link just the main CSS file.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is frames. That is if you want to use 'html' only. Yet frames are bad practice tbh, specially for this.

You can do the 'include' with Jquery too:

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#yourdiv").load("includefile.html"); 
});
</script>
```

An other way is to include with PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: He diddn't ask in JQuery tag Question.